# How to reverse array data?

Tags: php, css, arrays, wordpress

I want array 1,3,5,7,9 layout will be reverse from array 0,2,4,6,8,10
for example 1st row layout- image on left and description on righ, the 2nd row layout- image on right and description on left, and continuously.

This is my function.php code

```
<?php
            foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                $image = get_field('featured_image', $term);

                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="product-cat <?php echo $term->slug ?>">
                        <div class="two-col product-cat-image">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="two-col product-cat-details">
                            <?php
                                echo '<h4>'. $term->name .'</h4>';
                                echo '<p>'. $term->description .'</p>';
                                echo '<a class="product-cat-button" href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">See Products</a>';
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><?php
            } ?>
```

CSS code:

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.row .col {
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

And the result still like this
[image: result]

my expectation will be like this:
[image: expectation]

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Reversing an array (as per your title) is done with [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), but that doesn't seen to be what you want. I'm not sure from your question, what it is that you **do** want.

Comment: i want the layout will be reverse. for example 1st row- image on left and description on righ, the 2nd row- i want image on right and description on left,

Comment: @Reza Can I suggest you edit that into your question? The one answer that's posted is very wide of the mark.

Comment: you need to use css in order to achieve this easily

Comment: yes, im using css like display: flex; and flex-direction: row-reverse;  
i want to make this like dynamic from code. because the product will be auto update later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just need to change code in function.php as below.

```
<?php
    $i=0; 
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        $image = get_field('featured_image', $term);
        if($i % 2){ ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="product-cat <?php echo $term->slug ?>">
                    <div class="two-col product-cat-image">
                        <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="two-col product-cat-details">
                        <?php
                            echo '<h4>'. $term->name .'</h4>';
                            echo '<p>'. $term->description .'</p>';
                            echo '<a class="product-cat-button" href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">See Products</a>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else {?>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="product-cat <?php echo $term->slug ?>">
                    <div class="two-col product-cat-details">
                        <?php
                            echo '<h4>'. $term->name .'</h4>';
                            echo '<p>'. $term->description .'</p>';
                            echo '<a class="product-cat-button" href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">See Products</a>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="two-col product-cat-image">
                        <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
       $i++;
    }
?>
```

Hope now you got all things and let me know still any help need.

Comment: Please let me know answer is helpful or not

Comment: tanks, now the layout just like i want.

Comment: Instead of writing everything twice you should only alternate variables "left" and "right" and replace the content with it.

Comment: Okay great let me know still any help need.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the array_diff of [0,2,4,6,8,10].

Array_diff returns what is missing in the array, if we use an range() to create the reference array then it would look like:

```
$yourarray = [0,2,4,6,8,10];
$diff = array_diff(range(min($yourarray), max($yourarray)), $yourarray);
//[1,3,5,7,9]
```

https://3v4l.org/6QY3r

Comment: Good guess, but not even close! See the OP's comments above.

Comment: ![Expected layout](http://builditup.io/uploads/5cd109b3d577e91f13dc3c10/screen-shot-2019-05-07-at-11.29.15.png)

Comment: I have answered the only question there is. The only question you asked is *How to reverse array data?* And above is not reverse, but as you explain the problem it's the answer. If you want the answer to a different unasked question then maybe it should be included in the question itself?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add following css to achieve your desired output:

when odd `.product-cat` div found apply `order: 1;` to image container(`.product-cat-image`) and `order: 2;` to detail container(`.product-cat-details`)

when even `.product-cat` div found apply `order: 2;` to image container(`.product-cat-image`) and `order: 1;` to detail container(`.product-cat-details`)

```
.product-cat:nth-child(odd) .product-cat-image{
   -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}

.product-cat:nth-child(odd) .product-cat-details{
   -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}

.product-cat:nth-child(even) .product-cat-image{
   -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}

.product-cat:nth-child(even) .product-cat-details{
   -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
```